# Suppress warning output in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

I tried adding 2>/dev/null, &>/dev/null, etc, nothing seemed to suppress the warnings.

Answer (score 6):

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo 2>/dev/null | mysql -u root mysql
```

The command that is producing the error output to STDERR is the first command, not the second one.  Put the STDERR redirection before the pipe, and this should fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Better give your exact code attempt and warnings in your original post, but if you try this one :

```
{ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql; } 2>/dev/null
```

or

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql 2>/dev/null /usr/share/zoneinfo |
    mysql -u root mysql 2>/dev/null
```

that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing it on a subshell

```
( mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql ) &>/dev/null
```

Comment: No need to spawn a subshell !

Comment: @sputnick No need to get worked up lol. Obviously { } would have been a cheaper solution but I was expecting other things besides common redirection, which you probably haven't thought about.